# Ajax api call always goed in Failure

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am newly Working in Phone gap using Angular.js and Onsen. I am using api and it always goes in failure. This is my beginning to phonegap.

Please help me what is wrong is there in my java script.

My code for java script:-

```
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen']);

    var values="<?xml version='1.0'?><root><Email>Email/Email><UserPW>Password</UserPW><Method>ValidateUser</Method></root>";

    var yourApp = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);

    yourApp.controller("PageContrrol", function($scope) {

        $scope.Check = function(){       

           var name = document.getElementById("searchName");

           var pass = document.getElementById("searchPass");

           var NAME_VALUE=name.value;
           var PASS_VALUE=pass.value;

           var NM_LG=NAME_VALUE.length;
           var PS_LG=PASS_VALUE.length;

           if(NM_LG != 0 && PS_LG != 0){          
              // alert("Name is !"+NAME_VALUE);
               //$scope.Login = function() {};

          $.ajax({
        url: "URL",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",  
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
            $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
        });


            }else{
             alert("Please enter name or password!");
            }
        }


    });

    app.controller('PageController', function($scope) {
      var options = $scope.myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options;
      console.log(myNavigator.getPages().length);
      console.log(options);
    });
  </script>
```

If i have done any wrong code for ajax the please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

problem in you code

```
url: "URL",
```

this need to be replace by url you want to call

exampole `url: "www.google.com"`

---

one more thing if you are using angular js than use ajax call using angular js object ($http)

example to make ajax call is

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' },
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```

Read more here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: i have pass my "Url" in URL tag, Please give code for post method of XML.

Comment: @user3864262 - not able to get at all please refer the link and code provided by me ...which can help you what to pass to url

Comment: how to pass value in data Tag, Variable what i need to pass data like:- "<?xml version='1.0'?><root><Email>Email</Email><UserPW>Password</UserPW><Method>ValidateUser</Method></root>"

Comment: @user3864262 - suggest you to parse XML and pass data for that you can google it ..